# What are the locations of the junkyards?

Tags: burnout-paradise

I have been driving around for what seems like hours and found quite a large portion of... well, everything:

[image]

Specifically though, I am missing the location of one junkyard.

What are the locations of the junkyards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are five junk yard locations (one in each district) in the base game and an additional junk yard located on Big Surf Island.

The five junk yards in Paradise City are at the following locations;

- East Crawford Junk yard (starting junk yard): Intersection between East Crawford Drive and Angus Wharf
- Palm Bay Heights Junk yard: Hamilton Avenue
- Harbor Town Junk yard: Manners Avenue
- Silver Lake Junk yard: Intersection between Ross Drive and Nelson Way
- White Mountain Junk yard: Hans Way

Here is a map of all of the drive through locations, including junk yards;

[image]

The junk yard on Big Surf Island is located on Grange Hill;

[image]

A good resource for the main game can be [found here](http://www.senocular.com/burnout/), which details all of the drive throughs, race locations, jumps and smashables locations.

Comment: By comparing your map and OP's map, I have determined he is missing the Palm Bay Heights junkyard on Hamilton.